# ValueError: data_class [Twist] is not a class

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to get values from .yaml file for subscription and writing bag file. But i encounter with this error and i couldn't solve it.  I guess I can't define my values as a class name in code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import rospy 
import rosbag
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

filename='test.bag'
bag = rosbag.Bag(filename, 'w')


sensor_info=rospy.get_param("/bag/sensor_info") 
move_datatype=sensor_info[1]['datatype'] # Twist
move_topic=sensor_info[1]['topic_name'] # /cmd_vel

def move_callback(msg):
    x=msg

def main():
    global x
    rospy.init_node('rosbag_save', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber(move_topic,move_datatype(),move_callback)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        bag.write(f'{move_topic}',x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

this is my code

```
bag:
  sensor_info:
    - {"topic_name": "/multi_scan", "datatype": "LaserScan"}
    - {"topic_name": "/cmd_vel", "datatype": "Twist"}
```

and this is my .yaml file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399681/valueerror:-data_class-%5Btwist%5D-is-not-a-class/) by [anonymous60874](https://answers.ros.org/users/60874/anonymous60874/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is correct. data_class Twist is not a class.

This is wrong,

```
rospy.Subscriber(move_topic,move_datatype(),move_callback)
```

This is the correct way to subscribe to any topic,

```
rospy.Subscriber('/cmd_vel', Twist, callback)
```

BUT

In your case, `datatype`: `Twist` is coming as string and you do not want that. try to use [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#eval). For an example

```
rospy.Subscriber(move_topic, eval(move_datatype), move_callback)
```

---

Originally posted by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) with karma: 328 on 2022-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous60874](https://answers.ros.org/users/60874/anonymous60874/) on 2022-04-27**:
Yeah it really works. Thanks. I also tried "globals()[move_datatype]" and it works also too.